# Whos the biggest cat in the jungle?

Tags: python

I have to do an algorithm, heres what I need.

1. Set a value of "Lion" to the variable Answer;
2. input a users answer into a variable Guess;
3. if the user enters "Lion" the program outputs "Yes they are the biggest cat!";
4. Continue the game until the answer "Lion" or "lion" is reached.

I'm new to Python and this is what I have:

```
answer = "Lion" or "lion"
guess = input("Who's the biggest cat in the jungle? ")
while guess == answer:
    print("Yes they are the biggest cat!")
else:
    print("Try again")
```

The while loop just goes on forever and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the code you posted:

```
answer = "Lion" or "lion"
guess = input("Who's the biggest cat in the jungle? ")
while guess == answer:
    print("Yes they are the biggest cat!")
else:
     print("Try again")
```

That's a good start, but I see (at least) a few issues.

Variables are set to *one* value, not two. Hence answer cannot be both `Lion` and `lion` at the same time.

Since the guess is entered once and once only, it will never change inside the loop. Hence your loop, once started, will never exit.

And if you entered a value that *isn't* a lion, the loop will never start so it can never go back and ask you again.

So have a look at the following pseudo-code, Python-like since that's an ideal teaching language if you steer clear of its darker corners like list comprehension et seq :-).

You should be able to walk through it statement-by-statement and hopefully understand, at which pointing writing something similar in Python should be a bit easier:

```
guess = input "What is your name: "
while guess != "Pax" and guess != "pax":
    guess = input("I don't recognise you, try again: ")
print("My word, you are very handsome!")
```

You'll find it's very similar in structure to what you have but the sense of the `while` loop is reversed, continuing while you have the *wrong* answer, rather than while you have the right one.

Comment: I need to put the Answer AND the Guess variables in it though.

Comment: @Nathan, I understand that. But, if you came to SO expecting someone to do your assignment for you, you don't understand its intent. We're here to *assist* people, not do all their work for them. And you'll become a lot better coder if you have to put in a bit of "blood, sweat and tears" into the process :-)